# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQ L syntax; right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

Tags: python, mysql

Python MySQL Statement returning Error

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    tx.execute('select * from table where text1 = %s', (item['text1'], ))
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        tx.execute(\
            "INSERT INTO table (text3 table, text1, text2) "
            "values (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (item['text3'],
             item['table'],
             item['text1'],
             item['text2'],
             )
        )
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

but keep getting the following error :

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQ
>   L syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>    right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

can someone tell where I ignored  **)** ?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma after `text3` in your field spec.

```
INSERT INTO table (text3 table, text1, text2)
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO table (text3, table, text1, text2)
```

Also I don't think `table` is a valid table or column name if you don't enclose it in quotes, because it is a keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake now when editing in post. In the code script exist. there must be another error. Thanks you!

Comment: Like I said, `table` is a reserved word, so you probably need to quote the table name and column names with backticks.

Comment: I included the quotes table and get this error: **tx.execute('select * from 'table' where text1 = %s', (item['text1'], ))
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Not quotes, backticks.  In the top left of the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks leftclickben, I change but my problem persist: **mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQ
L syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
 right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")**

Comment: I didn't notice before but you don't have quotes around your values.  Instead of `values (%s, %s, %s, %s)` it should be `values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')`

Comment: Thanks again leftclickben. I try **values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')** but errors persist. Is the same error. Where can I post code spider.py and pipelines.py maybe someone can see me mistake?